# Dúvida if/else (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, if, else

Estou começando a estudar programação e no `JavaScript` tive um obstáculo com o `if/else`.

No código, o `if` sempre executa, mas o `else` não, já fiz várias modificações (inclusive adicionar o `addEventListener` no `JavaScript` para chamar o evento do `click`) mas nunca roda o código todo, onde estou errando?

Segue o código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Nacionalidade</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>BRASILEIRO OU ESTRANGEIRO?</h1>
  Digite o seu país de origem:<input type="text" name="pais" id="pais">
  <input type="button" value="Verificar" onclick="clique()">
  <script>
    function clique(){
      let pais='Basill'
      if(pais!=='Brasil'){
        alert(`Você é ESTRANGEIRO!`)
      } else{
        alert(`Você é BRASILEIRO`)
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: esse código cai no `else` não entendi a dúvida

Comment: qual é o problema? já visto que por fixar um valor na variavel pais sempre vai entrar no else?

Comment: a sua duvida é porque tem a caixa de texto para digitar o pais?

Comment: Se a variável `pais` nunca muda, o seu programa vai sempre se comportar da mesma maneira. Tem uma falha lógica aí. Note que em momento algum você coleta o valor que o usuário digitou no input. Para isso faça `let pais = document.getElementById('pais').value`.

Comment: *Basill* sempre vai ser diferente de *Brasil*.

Comment: Obrigada pela ajuda entendi onde errei a principio mas esse é o único erro de lógica? Pq sigo com o mesmo problema.

Answer (score 1):

Como mencionado pelo usuário @yoyo no comentário, sua variável nunca muda de valor. Logo, nunca vai cair em uma condição diferente.

Dado que precisa resgatar o valor do elemento `input` com id `pais`, você pode fazer de uma das duas formas:

```
let elementoPais = document.getElementById('pais');
```

ou

```
let elementoPais = document.querySelector('#pais');
```

A diferença **visual** entre os dois é que no segundo exemplo (utilizando o método `querySelector`) um ID é buscado a partir do caractere `#` como prefixo. Utilizando o `getElementById` como exemplo para entender o que acontece:

- `document` -> página
- `.getElementById("pais")` -> busque um elemento pelo seu atributo `id` onde o valor seja `"pais"`;

Nesse caso teremos um acesso ao elemento como variável no script:

```
let elementoPais = document.getElement...
```

Por termos um objeto que representa o elemento na página, podemos acessar o seu valor. Para isso temos a propriedade `value` (valor):

```
elementoPais.value
```

A propriedade citada retorna o que estiver dentro do campo, ou seja, seu valor. Dessa forma, a sua condição funcionaria:

```
function clique() {
  let elementoPais = document.getElementById('pais'); // Buscando o elemento pelo ID
  let pais = elementoPais.value; // Acessando seu valor
  if (pais !== 'Brasil') {
    alert(`Você é ESTRANGEIRO!`);
  } else{
    alert(`Você é BRASILEIRO`);
  }
}
```

Agora o resultado pode mudar já que depende do valor inserido pelo usuário e não de um valor fixo na variável `pais`, como "`let pais = 'Basill'`".

Comment: Obrigada pela ajuda. Porém sigo com o mesmo problema, vc consegui ver mais algum erro na minha lógica?

Comment: @TatiBezerra veja se não está digitando o valor com letras minúsculas (dado que está comparando o valor digitado com "Brasil", com "B" maiusculo) e se buscou pelo elemento correto.

Comment: É isso mesmo! Agora está rodando certo. Se não for muito incomodo, você pode me dizer como eu elimino essa limitação, para que independente de ser letras maiúsculas ou minusculas ele funcione corretamente?

Comment: Mude o valor "Brasil" para "brasil" e utilize `pais.toLowerCase()` para deixar todas as letras do valor digitado minúsculas. O mesmo poder ser feito mudando o valor para "BRASIL" e utilizando `pais.toUpperCase()`.